# Conexión a base de datos con kinterbasdb

Tags: python, firebird

Tengo un grave problema, realice una aplicación en python que necesito que se ejecute al inicio de windows, pero resulta que el servidor que trabaja con Firebird tarda varios segundos en arrancar y eso me causa problemas de conexión con el programa de python.
Estoy buscando la forma de manipular esa conexión:

```
conn = kinterbasdb.connect(host,user,pass)
```

Estoy buscando la solucion, pero si alguien sabe como hacerlo  le agradecería su su comentario.
Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué error te está arrojando?

Comment: @César el error:  `cursor=conn.cursor() Attributederror:'bool object has not attributed cursor'` . Aclaro que si ejecuto el .exe luego funciona perfecto y que he creado un .cmd para que la aplicación .py compilada en .exe tenga un buen retraso de varios segundos, pero me sigue tirando ese error.

Answer (score 2):

Es un poco complicado sacar conclusiones de solo esa línea de código pero si la conexión está retornando `False` (por el error del comentario) al fallar en conectar, entonces me parece que lo más sencillo es que se siga intentando hasta que el servidor Firebird esté listo:

```
import time

conn = kinterbasdb.connect(host, user, pass)
while conn == False:
    time.sleep(5) # Cada 5 segundos
    conn = kinterbasdb.connect(host, user, pass)
cursor = conn.cursor()
# ...
```

En vez de esperar una cantidad de segundos inicialmente, el proceso va a seguir intentando hasta encontrar la conexión. Puedes convertir la cantidad de segundos a esperar en un parámetro configurable en algún lado.

Imaginando que tienes algun archivo de configuraciones tipo `settings.py`:

```
CONNECTION_SLEEP_SECONDS = 5
MAXIMUM_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS = 3 # Por la recomendación de @jasilva
```

Entonces el código quedaría así:

```
import time
import settings

conn = kinterbasdb.connect(host, user, pass)
attempts = 0
while conn == False or attempts <= settings.MAXIMUM_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS:
    time.sleep(settings.CONNECTION_SLEEP_SECONDS)
    conn = kinterbasdb.connect(host, user, pass)
    attempts += 1
if conn == False:
    raise Exception('La base de datos no está disponible')
cursor = conn.cursor()
# ...
```

### Nota:

Estoy asumiendo que la función `connect` retorna un booleano (`False`) basado en el comentario que has proporcionado sobre el error.

Comment: Valdria la pena, poner un atributo `maximumConnectionAttempt` para no estar infinitamente en el loop

Comment: @jasilva si, sería lo más adecuado. Lo agrego

Comment: @jasilva Utilizo Try: except: para validar la conexión, también uso el script que colocaron en el comentario y me dice este error conn = kinterbasdb.connect(host, user, pass) y TypeError: bool object no attributed __getitem__ ... Entiendo la lógica que me plantean ustedes, que es igual a la mia. Ahora lo que no entiendo es por que al inicio de windows la aplicación (con cualquier tiempo de ejecución) me sigue tirando errores, pero si yo la vuelvo ejecutar manualmente, esta funciona perfecto. :( –